# WIX Navigation V2 - Hide bottom tab bar when push to a new screen

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation, react-native-navigation-v2

#### Issue Description

I have TabBar base application, in one of my tab I need to push it to another screen but the tab bar should not display in the pushed screen. But the bottom bar is still existing in the pushed screen.
What I want to achieved is not totally hide the bottom tab bar but to put the pushed screen on top of the tab bar.

#### Steps to Reproduce / Code Snippets / Screenshots

Here's my code to display the tab bar application:

`bottomTabs: {
      id: 'BottomTabsId',
      children: [
        {
          stack: {
            children: [
              {
                component: {
                  name: 'Home',
                  options: {
                    topBar: {
                      backButton: {
                        title: 'Back',
                      },
                      title: {
                        text: 'Home'
                      }
                    },
                    bottomTab: {
                      fontSize: 12,
                      text: 'Home',
                      icon: require('./src/assets/home.png'),
                      selectedIcon: require('./src/assets/home_active.png')
                    },
                  },
                },
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          stack: {
            children: [
              {
                component: {
                  name: 'Booking',
                  options: {
                    topBar: {
                      title: {
                        text: 'Booking'
                      }
                    },
                    bottomTab: {
                      text: 'Booking',
                      fontSize: 12,
                      icon: require('./src/assets/booking.png'),
                      selectedIcon: require('./src/assets/booking_active.png')
                    }
                  }
                },
              }
            ],
          },
        },
      ],
    },`

[image: image from ios]
**The Tab bar is still existing :(**

[image: image from ios]

**What I want to achieve is this**
[image: image from ios]

---

#### Environment

- React Native Navigation version: 2.0.2454
- React Native version: 0.56
- Platform(s) (iOS, Android, or both?): IOS
- Device info (Simulator/Device? OS version? Debug/Release?): Simulator IOS 11

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to push that screen with `bottomTabs.visible: false` option:

```
Navigation.push(this.props.componentId, {
  component: {
    name: 'your.component.name',
    options: {
      bottomTabs: {
        visible: false,
        drawBehind: true
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: it doesn't work on both iOS and Android? Can you try using the latest `react-native-navigation`?

Answer (score 1):

For android hide bottom tab in v2

```
componentDidMount() {
    Navigation.mergeOptions(this.props.componentId, {
        bottomTabs: {
          visible: false,
          drawBehind:true
        }
      });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue. I found a way to hide the `tabs` programmatically when pushing new screen.

You can hide tab in your newly pushed screen using. Write the below toggle inside constructor.

```
this.props.navigator.toggleTabs({
      to: 'hidden',
      animated: false,
    });
```

Comment: this looks like `v1` syntax